# encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long) Django send_mail

Tags: python, django, unicode, backend, python-unicode

When sending a message to the mail via the send_mail function, an error appears - encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
What could be the problem and how to make the encoding work correctly
And what is most interesting, everything worked fine on another computer and messages were sent without any problems, so the error is clearly not in settings.py

settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

views.py file:

```
def post_share(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug, status='published')
    sent = False
    form = EmailPostForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
        name_user = cd["email"].replace("@gmail.com", "")
        subject = f'Пользователь ({name_user}) рекомендует к прочтению — {post.title}'
        message = f'Прочитайте "{post.title}" по ссылке - {post_url}\n\nСообщение: {cd["comments"]}'
        send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [cd['to']])
        sent = True
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'sent': sent})
```

I tried to use the idna library, but it did not work, the same error was displayed

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I will now try to edit it more clearly

Comment: Did the recipient address contain any special character?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share full traceback…

Comment: @Dauros it contains the @ symbol as it is sent by email

Comment: @Dauros иut the interesting thing is that this error occurs even if I pass a normal string